# SQL Server - Percentage change calculation applied only on rows where two fields are the same

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get a Percentage change column. However, the calculation should always skip (or make NULL the first occurrence and reset for every new address:unit combination. For example address:unit "A" has sold several times over the last 20 years, so get the percentage difference for each year with the first year omitted. However, when we reach the row address:unit "B", reset by skipping or making NULL, and on second row of address:unit "B" begin calculation. And so on with a every other unique address:unit. The information below illustrates what I have written.

Table (input):

```
address,       unit, sale_date, sale_price
123 Sesame St, 11B,   7/2/2005,  250,000
123 Sesame St, 11B,   8/1/2011,  500,000
123 Sesame St, 11B,   3/5/2019,  750,000
200 Jones St,   3W,  11/6/2015,  465,000
200 Jones St,   3W,   4/6/2018,  690,000
```

Desired output:

```
address,       unit, sale_date, sale_price,  percent_change
123 Sesame St, 11B,   7/2/2005,  250,000,    NULL
123 Sesame St, 11B,   8/1/2011,  430,000,    0.72 
123 Sesame St, 11B,   3/5/2019,  700,000,    0.63
200 Jones St,   3W,  11/6/2015,  465,000,    NULL
200 Jones St,   3W,   4/6/2018,  690,000,    0.48
```

Incorrect Query:

```
SELECT address, unit, sale_date, sale_price - COALESCE(LAG(sale_price) OVER(ORDER BY address, unit, sale_date) AS percent_change 
FROM TABLE
```

How can I fix query to get the Desired Output?

Answer (score 2):

With lag() window function:

```
select *,
  round(1.0 * (sale_price - lag(sale_price) over (partition by address, unit order by sale_date)) /
  lag(sale_price) over (partition by address, unit order by sale_date) percent_change, 2)

from tablename
```

Or with a CTE to make the code more readable:

```
with cte as (
  select *, lag(sale_price) over (partition by address, unit order by sale_date) prevprice
  from tablename
)  
select 
  address, unit, sale_date, sale_price,
  round(1.0 * (sale_price - prevprice) / prevprice, 2) percent_change
from cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fd0ef38a2aa52b3d1a7f8cd23abfc384).
Results:

```
> address       | unit | sale_date           | sale_price | percent_change
> :------------ | :--- | :------------------ | ---------: | :-------------
> 123 Sesame St | 11B  | 02/07/2005 00:00:00 |     250000 | null
> 123 Sesame St | 11B  | 01/08/2011 00:00:00 |     430000 | 0.72
> 123 Sesame St | 11B  | 05/03/2019 00:00:00 |     700000 | 0.63
> 200 Jones St  | 3W   | 06/11/2015 00:00:00 |     465000 | null
> 200 Jones St  | 3W   | 06/04/2018 00:00:00 |     690000 | 0.48
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test on a larger dataset.

Comment: I added the address field to the partition.                                                ```select *,
   1.0 * (sale_price - lag(sale_price) over (partition by address, unit order by sale_date)) /
  lag(sale_price) over (partition by address, unit order by sale_date) percent_change

from tablename ```

Comment: Correct, I missed the *address:unit combination* part in your question.